# Best Way to host dynamic image with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a website where I need to dynamically host images. My intention is to host the images with full URL.

I tried CDN but come to know it has a limitation of that image will only be available 15 mins after upload.

Other options is Blob storage, when I read the [document](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/storage/) it says "Block blobs" are most ideal for image and media content. Therefore, I am trying to use that.

So, I've following questions:

1. What is the best way to host images on Azure for such requirements?
2. If I use Blob storage then how can I get the full URL so that I can that URL to load images in my product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a *best* way to store images. Some people store them in blob storage (as you referenced), some go with database engines... But, since you asked specifically about how to interact with blob storage and URI's:

All blobs are referenced by uri: `http(s)://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname`

You can set every blob to private or public (whether at blob or container level), and then either return URI's to your user/webpage (if public) or generate a Shared Access Policy or Shared Access Signature to temporariliy grant access to a private blob (I'll leave that as an exercise for you to look up).

It's completely up to you to create containers and blobs as needed. How you find a blob later is also up to you, so you'll need to think about how you store their names or their URIs (e.g. in a database table somewhere). You can always iterate through containers to search for a given blob, but that is time-consuming, vs direct-retrieval (again, assuming you've stored the URI as metadata somewhere in a database).

Comment: Thanks David! Your explanation very much answers my questions.